# Validate range for fetching records

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a regular expression  which requires the following pattern **with and without spaces**

- Comma separated list of alphanumeric values : DG1, D3 OR R4,UI2
- Comma separated list of alphanumeric and numeric values : D1, 2 OR D1,2
- Range of alphanumeric values : DG1 - DG5 OR DG1-DG5
- Range of alphanumeric and numeric values : DG1 - 8 OR DG1-8 OR 8-DG11 OR 8 - DG13
- A combination of range and comma separated values : DG1, DG3-DG7 OR DG1,DG3-DG6
- A combination of range and comma separated alphanumeric and numeric values : DG1, 3-DG7 OR 1,DG3-6
- No other special character should be allowed other than comma and hyphen
- 2 special characters cannot come together
- Cannot start or end with a special character

Invalid values may be

- ,1,DG1
- -DG1-5
- DG1 - 3 - GP9
- 1,F4,
- RE3-
- 1,-G3
- 5,S3,-9

Comment: That's great, but what is your question?

Comment: We'd like to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Lucas: It's a simple 'give me teh codez'.

Comment: now I'm using the regex provided 'M42' ie ^[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?(?:,[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?)*$, its working fine for inputs without spaces but not for the ones which has spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use:

```
^([A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?)(?:,(?1))*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                       : Start of string
    (                   : begin group 1
        [A-Z0-9]+       : 1 or more alphanum
        (?:             : begin NON capture group
            -           : literally -
            [A-Z0-9]+   : 1 or more alphanum
        )?              : end group, optional
    )                   : end group 1
    (?:                 : begin NON capture group
        ,               : literally ,
        (?1)            : repeat regex in group 1
    )?                  : end group,optional
$
```

If `(?1)` doesn't work, have to duplicate the relevant part:

```
^[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?(?:,[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?)*$
```

If you want to deal with optional spaces:

```
^\s*[A-Z0-9]+(?:\s*-\s*[A-Z0-9]+)?(?:\s*,\s*[A-Z0-9]+(?:\s*-\s*[A-Z0-9]+)?)*\s*$
```

Comment: Thanks, its working for values without spaces but not for the ones with spaces